# ORDER BY on multiple fields at the same time while ignoring specific value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of products, some are on special, some are used.

```
| Desc       |  Sale price | Special price | Used price
--------------------------------------------------------
| Product 1  |       20.00 |         15.00 |       0.00
| Product 2  |       38.00 |          0.00 |      22.00
| Product 3  |       21.00 |          0.00 |       0.00
| Product 4  |       16.00 |         12.00 |       8.00
| Product 5  |        0.00 |          0.00 |      25.00
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to sort the products (Within the same query) **from the lowest to the highest value within the three columns while ignoring all the 0.00** (Ex.: Used 0.00 represents that no used are available for that specific product)..

The result would be this :

```
| Desc       |  Sale price | Special price | Used price
--------------------------------------------------------
| Product 4  |       16.00 |         12.00 |      *8.00   8.00 is the lowest
| Product 1  |       20.00 |        *15.00 |       0.00   15.00 is the lowest, 1x 0.00 is ignored
| Product 3  |      *21.00 |          0.00 |       0.00   21.00 is the lowest, 2x 0.00 are ignored
| Product 2  |       38.00 |          0.00 |     *22.00   22.00 is the lowest, 1x 0.00 is ignored
| Product 5  |        0.00 |          0.00 |     *25.00   25.00 is the lowest, 2x 0.00 are ignored
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **Thanks**!

Comment: Have the value `NULL` instead of `0.00`, or preferably a table with `product_id`, `type` and `price`. Would make more sense in the long run.

Comment: I totally agree @RobinCastlin :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a trick using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`

```
ORDER BY LEAST(IF(SalePrice = 0, GREATEST(SalePrice, SpecialPrice, UsedPrice) + 1, SalePrice), 
               IF(SpecialPrice = 0, GREATEST(SalePrice, SpecialPrice, UsedPrice) + 1, SpecialPrice), 
               IF(UsedPrice = 0, GREATEST(SalePrice, SpecialPrice, UsedPrice) + 1, UsedPrice)) ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b7c/1)

Comment: [Comparison Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: This is great, thanks, I'll study the use of LEAST(), GREATEST() and the other operators unknown to me. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the doc right now, may I ask why you add +1 within the IF statement??

Comment: actually it's optional. it just making one more greater than the highest value `:)`